# Orchard cms: display registration page link on layout page Extended Registration module

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, orchardcms, orchard-modules

So I'm developing a new web site with the Orchard cms and I have installed the profiles module and the Extended Registration module, but there is still no link on my pages to the Registration page.

I have signed out to test if it appears then but still nothing.

If you know any specifics I would prefer the link to display inside the div with the id of NavAux. This is inside the Layout.cshtml file if you didn't know.

Comment: Which orchard version you use? You might need to update the modules to be compatible with your orchard version. Usually that means to choose another Target Framework for the module's project. Its probably also logged in the log files under Orchard.Web/App_Data/Logs